# react-router-dom v6: useNavigate() not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**So I'm trying to redirect the Add to Cart button to Cart screen but it isn't working**

ProductScreen.js 
useNavigate() redirects to the link but doesn't display anything

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const ProductScreen = () => {

  const { id } = useParams()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const [ qty, setQty ] = useState(0)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails(id))
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <>
        <ListGroup.Item className='d-grid gap-2'>
            <Button 
                onClick={() => navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)}
                className='btn-block' 
                type='button' 
                size='lg'
                disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
             > Add to Cart </Button>
        </ListGroup.Item>
    </>
  )
}
```

CartScreen.js

```
const CartScreen = () => {
   return (
      <h1>Cart</h1>
   )
}

export default CartScreen
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import Header from './components/Header'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen'
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
            <Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen />}>
              <Route path='/cart/:id?' element={<CartScreen />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Now, this is where the problem lies. As far as I know, the cart screen should be displayed but all I get is a blank screen.

I get this one issue on console screen that I can't put my finger on

```
No routes matched location "/cart/6239f6707dfb138e900d42d7?qty=2"
```

I am very new to this coz everything has changed from the last version. I know this is very simple but I'm stuck here and can't go any further... Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: remove the query in your app.js <Route path='/cart/:id' element={<CartScreen />} />

Comment: Typo, remove the trailing `"?"` from the `path` prop, it should be `path='/cart/:id'`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you maybe be using nested routes incorrectly in order to achieve what you are supposed to:

With this nesting:

```
<Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen />}>
  <Route path='/cart/:id?' element={<CartScreen />} />
</Route>
```

The above will match:

```
/cart/cart/6239f6707dfb138e900d42d7?qty=2
```

Shouldn't the nesting be?:

```
<Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen />}>
  <Route path='/:id?' element={<CartScreen />} />
</Route>
```

in order to to match:

```
/cart/6239f6707dfb138e900d42d7?qty=2
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you may have forgotten to use `<Outlet />` to render content in `<CartScreen />`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31849536)